# Why are emojis not working in Chrome Extension popups?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, emoji, browser-extension

In the extension popup HTML I have placed an emoji, like this:

`<div>`
 `<input id="user_input" autofocus>`
`</div`

But when I open the extension popup, this shows up:

[image]

I'd really like to use emojis in the extension HTML document. I there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: Try saving the html file in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't help.

Comment: Your code works for me so I'm inclined to think you didn't save it in UTF-8 or there's a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saving the file as UTF8 with BOM fixed it.

Answer (score 12):

Adding

```html
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
```

in `<head></head>` block fixed it for me.